# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp()

Tags: wp-blog-header.php

I keep getting the below message and I can't access my website:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp() in
> /home/q77bvndhxly7/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:16 Stack trace: #0
> /home/q77bvndhxly7/public_html/index.php(17): require() #1 {main}
> thrown in /home/q77bvndhxly7/public_html/wp-blog-header.php on line 16

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something's broken in your copy of WordPress, either wp-load.php or includes/functions.php or something else in between. Take a backup of everything, then try following the manual update instructions here

https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

to replace all of the WordPress core file with a fresh copy.

Comment: This has been happening very frequently in the last 12 months if you search for this bug. I'm not sure what is causing it but I've had it happen on 2 fresh installs of WordPress on 2 different sites in the same week.